# Delete command in a database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my project, in database, I have a table for bookmarks. I want to delete rows form this table. I write a method to delete rows with their id. but my code does not work.

**Here is my delete method (to delete bookmark in database):**

```
public void delete_bookmark(int id) {
        Log.e("delete_bookmark"," is running");
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_BOOKMARKS + " WHERE " + BOOKMARK_ID + " = " + id);
        db.close();
}
```

**And this code is in my activity:**

```
public void deleteBookmark() {
     SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
     sqLiteHelper.delete_bookmark(ads.getId());
     Log.e("bookmarktable", sqLiteHelper.get_bookmarks().toString());
     Toast.makeText(this, "از لیست علاقه مندی ها حذف شد", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: is `BOOKMARK_ID` a variable or a column name?

Comment: @AyushGupta BOOKMARK_ID is a column name

Comment: Then why are you appending it to the string using `+`?

Comment: please dont use hard code for table names and fields.

Comment: is it throwing an exception? Or it's not doing any thing?

Comment: This is the correct *command* (not a *query*!): `db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_BOOKMARKS + " WHERE BOOKMARK_ID = " + id);`

Comment: @KlingKlang, I Think BOOKMARK_ID is a variable that holds a field name and could not be considered as field name itself. For example BOOKMARK_ID field can be **ID** or **BID** or something else

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe If you take your time and read the comments above, the OP said: `BOOKMARK_ID is a column name`

Comment: @KlingKlang okay thanks I get the point. In that case you are right. That **may** be the case for `TABLE_BOOKMARKS` also.

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe Yes, absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
public void Delete(String tablename, String pos) {
    try {
        db.delete(tablename, "BOOKMARK_ID" + "='" + pos + "'", null);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```